# Swift Firestore pagination is retrieving the next batch of documents but replacing the first batch

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

In Swift I'm trying to implement pagination and I'm able to retrieve the next batch of documents, but, instead loading them at the bottom of the UITableView, it's replacing the first batch. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
private var currentKey: String?

func fetchGlimpseData() {
    if currentKey == nil {
        GLIMPSE_ALL_USERS_DATA.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: true).limit(to: 3)
            .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            
            guard let last = snapshot?.documents.last else { return }
            guard let allObjects = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            
            allObjects.forEach( { document in
                self.glimpse.removeAll()
                self.glimpse = Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                self.glimpseTableView.reloadData()
            })
            self.currentKey = last.documentID
        }
    } else if currentKey != nil {
        GLIMPSE_ALL_USERS_DATA.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: true).limit(to: 3).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            
            guard let lastDoc = snapshot?.documents.last else { return }
            
            if snapshot?.isEmpty == false {
                GLIMPSE_ALL_USERS_DATA.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: true).start(afterDocument: lastDoc).getDocuments { ( snapshot, error) in
                    guard let snap = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                    snap.forEach( { document in
                        self.glimpse = Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                    })
                }
            }
            self.glimpseTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    
    if maxOffset - currentOffset <= 40 {
        fetchGlimpseData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the call to `self.glimpse.removeAll()` here:

```
GLIMPSE_ALL_USERS_DATA.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: true).limit(to: 3)
    .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    
    guard let last = snapshot?.documents.last else { return }
    guard let allObjects = snapshot?.documents else { return }
    
    allObjects.forEach( { document in
        self.glimpse.removeAll()
        self.glimpse = Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
        ...
```

Since you first remove all data from `self.glimpse`, the previous page of data is removed after you add the new one.

To keep both pages, don't call `self.glimpse.removeAll()`.

---

As you pointed out in the comments, your second page is loaded by the else block - so the above can't cause that problem.

In the else block you also replace the existing value of `self.glimpse` with each snapshot though in this line:

```
self.glimpse = Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
```

So: whatever value `self.glimpse` had before that line, it'll be gone after the line has run.

I'd expect to see something where you *add* the `Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)` to `self.glimpse` instead of replacing it each time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Frank. During the second call self.glimpse.removeAll() should not be a problem, at that point currentkey is not nil and the "else" block is the one been called.

Comment: Oops... I inverted the conditions in my mind. The else block also replaces the existing value of `self.glimpse` with each snapshot though: `self.glimpse = Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)`. I'd expect to see something where you *add* the `Glimpse.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)` to `self.glimpse` instead of replacing it each time.

Comment: got it, makes sense, I have to append the new documents to self.glimpse. The only problem I'm having now is that it loads the next batch of documents, but, when I reach the bottom, it loads the same last 3 over and over.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to add a `startAfter` call with the last document you've loaded so far, to get rid of that.